# Cloudbees Play: How to secure credentials used for testing and production

Tags: security, playframework, cloudbees

Requirement: Secure credentials used for testing and production environment.

My Approach:

1. Store the config parameters in a local file (i.e. this file should not be in git-repo)
2. At run-time, provide the location of this file to PLAY using APP_CONFIG_FILE env variable or command-line parameter.

Here are details of the problem I am facing. Kindly suggest any working solution for this requirement.

In Testing Environment (using Jenkins):

1. Store the file in /private/myaccount/testing.conf
2. Select "Mount Cloudbees Dev@cloud private WebDav Repository"
3. In "Build -> Excute Shell", add the following "export APP_CONFIG_FILE=/private/myaccount/testing.conf"
4. In `Global.java` of {lay application, get the filename using the following: String configFilename = Play.application().configuration().getString(APP_CONFIG_FILE);

**Problem:**
In test-suite, getting APP_CONFIG_FILE as null.
Question: How to pass environment variable for "play test"

In Production:

1. Store the file in /private/myaccount/production.conf

**Problem:**
How to access the private repository in RUN@cloud? I could not find documentation on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime best option is to use [configuration parameters](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters).

File system is not persistent on the cloud. However, if you would like to access to the ephermal file system on the cloud, you can get the path using System.getProperty("java.io.tempDir").

AFAIK, you cannot access to DEV from RUN and viceversa. I think you should manage your secrets independently on DEV and RUN.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not accessing DEV from RUN and viceversa. They are independent environments. I find different issues with each of these environment as I outlined above. I have put them in same thread because my objective for both environments is same i.e. secure the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

configuration parameters are injected as system properties, so you can rely on good old System.getProperty() to get production configuration values.

Comment: I am getting null for System.getProperty(APP_CONFIG_FILE) in the Testing Environment. I am not sure why "play test" does not get the system property.